# Tomcat virtual hosting under Amazon EC2 instance behing ELB: Which host gets the ELB HTTP health check query?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, virtualhost

I'm using Tomcat inside two Ubuntu instances, which are behind an ELB (elastic load balancer) in Amazon Web Services cloud. Each Tomcat installation has several virtual hosts in the same engine. The ELB makes the healthy checks to see if the hosts are alive. But inside a host, which of the Tomcat virtual hosts gets the health check request? When I define the health check, I specify just the port and the LAST PART of the URL. So I don't know what is the complete URL of the health check that gets performed. Right now, the Tomcat virtual host that is declared as the default host in the engine is the one getting the checks, just because it is the default host. But actually that host is not the one that will serve the application, so it should NOT be the one receiving the check requests.

In other words: If the check uses port 80 and the last part of the URL is "/hello.html", what would the complete checking URL be here:
http:///hello.html

What is the content of "what comes here?"? The local/private IP of the instance?

Answer (score 1):

It's always going to go to the virtual host defined as localhost.

I would suggest setting up the virtual host that you want getting the health checks as localhost, and then setting a [host name alias](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Host%20Name%20Aliases) on that virtual host to the domain name you want to point to it.

So you would have:

```
  <Host name="localhost" ...>
    <Alias>mydomain.com</Alias>
  </Host>
```